# Is it possible to select one radio button and disable the rest for a particular multiple choice question using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to select one radio button and disable the rest for a particular multiple choice question using jquery? Can you show me with an example I am new to coding world

Comment: Could you explain a little better the sitiation? When you create a radio group, selecting one automatically de-selects the rest, why is there a need to disable it? I just want to understand better what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am encountering some problem while storing values.I know by default when u select one radio button rest gets deselected but I want to know if it’s possible to select one and disable the rest

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```js
$("#el").prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script let's you select one radio button and inmediately disables the rest

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="">
    <input type="radio" name="language" value="en">English
    <input type="radio" name="language" value="es">Spanish
    <input type="radio" name="language" value="ja">Japanese
</div>

<script>
$('input[name="language"]').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings().attr('disabled', true);
});
</script>
```

I put the radios inside a div to avoid the siblings affecting other things.

However, I don't think this is your problem. If all radios have the same **name** they shouldn't interfere with the storing of data in any strange way.

Comment: Thank you it works now. Yeah it should not interfere while storing. I guess I have a problem when the value gets stored in the server maybe some code error